# how to read json file before calling controller using resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to read json file and get data before controller call .But I am not able to display the output why ?

I make one factory  like this

```
.factory('abc',function($http){

  return{
    loadData:function(successCallback,errorCallbak){
      return $http.get('data.json').success(successCallback).error(errorCallbak)
    }

  }


})
```

I used resolve function like that

```
resolve: {
        user: function (abc) {
         return abc.loadData

        }
      }
```

But it not displaying the output in HTML why ?

```
template: '<b>Welcome {{home.user.name}}!</b>',
```

Expected output is **Welcome Naveen**

Comment: while calling `abc.loadData` i don't see you are passing `successCallback` & `errorCallback` there and additionally resolve function returns promise object. but here you have used callback, that might be another reason behind it..

Comment: ok i will try and update you

Comment: Not getting could you please update my plunker

Comment: I don't see plunkr link here

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Whr3a1543uy2Ji8kqJU3?p=preview

Comment: look at mine answer..in which I made a working plunkr with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve function should always return a promise, as I said in my comments. So instead of using `callbacks you should return promise`object`from the`abc`service`loadData` function.

So for converting your service `loadData` function to promise you need to change `.success` & `.error` function to `.then` function, which returns a promise object (`$http.get` method returns promise)like `.then(successCallback, errorCallbak)`.

**Factory**

```
.factory('abc', function($http) {
  return {
    loadData: function(successCallback, errorCallbak) {
      //returned promise object using `.then` as $http.get function return promise
      return $http.get('data.json').then(successCallback, errorCallbak)
    }
  }
})
```

**Resolve**

```
resolve: {
    user: function(abc) {
      return abc.loadData(success, error);

      function success(res) {
        console.log(res)
        return res.data;
      }

      function error(res) {
        return []; // or whatever default data, maybe {}
      }

    }
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hIJITLP9HW8Vd5BjQvy?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide success and failure callbacks

http://plnkr.co/edit/HBDMMb7CWAN9BXTDz6fb?p=preview

```
resolve: {
    user: function (abc) {
     return abc.loadData(success, error);
     function success (res) {
       return res.data;
     } 
     function error (res) {
       return []; // or whatever default data, maybe {}
     } 

    }
  }
```

Comment: in your plunkr, you missed the data property, so instead of returning `res.data`, you just returned `res`